# Elements are too far apart and I can't move image up

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui

I'm working on a screen for my app, and for the life of me I can't get align my elements how I'm trying. What am I doing wrong?

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
```

One element stays towards bottom. It looks like it might be due to boundaries? I could be wrong though.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPJJB.png)

Comment: logo size is too big `500.dp` That's the reason you can't move image up. Reduce the size or set only `width`

Answer (score 0):

For the first Image you set size to be 500dp. Either remove the size or change according to your needs